# How to calculate extra large numbers with bc in bash

Tags: bash, math, bc

I have a file with 1800 lines that look like this

```
600.76
600.66
700.44
566.66
Ect..
```

I made a bash script to calculate the mean.

Now I first made a variable to count the total column lines like:

```
Lines="$(awk 'END{print NR}' file.txt)"
```

Then another variable for the sum of that column like this:

```
Sum="$(awk '{s+1=$1}END {print s}' file.txt)"
```

Lastly I'm finding the mean like this:

```
Echo "scale=2 ; $Sum / $Lines" | bc
```

With debugging enabled It returns:

```
+echo 'scale=2 ; 1.72161e+06 / 1800'
(Standard_1): syntax error
```

I realize now bc doesn't do scientific notation but how do I get around this.

I'm OK with short handing the decimal by restricting it to 2 or 3 places.

Comment: Why not just use `awk`?

Comment: how about just `awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/NR}'`?

Comment: @twallberg awk returns scientific notation after the answer gets too large. Which is the original problem

Comment: @theloosegoos The perhaps `awk '{sum+=$1}END{printf "%f\n", sum/NR}` would provide better results. `awk` has a `printf` implementation that mimics a lot of (but not all) the C version features...

Comment: @theloosegoos Are any lines in the input file in scientific notation?

Comment: No I'm saying the file only has one column and it's a number like this 857.54. There are 1800 lines simular to that. When you sum the file the out put is in scientific notation. There for when I attempt to pass that to bc for some division it tosses the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bc -l` for both summation and final division:

```
sum=0
count=0
while read number; do
  number=$(printf "%f\n" $number) # get rid of scientific notation
  sum=$(echo "$sum" '+' "$number" | bc -l)
  count=$((count + 1))
done < input
avg=$(echo $sum / $count | bc -l)
echo $avg
```

Comment: This will lead me to the same error because the sum of the file is to large it's expressed in scientific notation.

Comment: @theloosegoos No, it won't. `bc` doesn't use scientific notation. It is an arbitrary precision calculator.

Comment: the root of the problem is when the column of my file is added. The sum is so large it's expressed in scientific notation. So when I pass the the sum of the column to bc it will toss the error because it doesn't accept the notation.

Comment: @theloosegoos, can you provide the input file?

Comment: its the very first example in the post given. Aside from its just the first of 1800 lines

Comment: @theloosegoos, bc never uses scientific notation. If you still get an error, then I guess that one of the input numbers is already represented in scientific notation. You may use `printf` to convert number back to ordinary notation. I've updated code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary to use awk. Simple oneliner can do the job.

```
echo "scale=2; ("$(paste -sd+ file.txt)")"/$(wc -l <file.txt)|bc
```

Comment: This still sends bc into a error it can't handle scientific notation this happens whenext the answer goes above a certain value.